# How to undo git rm -rf dirname without a first commit?

Tags: git, commit, delete-file, undo, rm

I did:

```
git init
git add .
git rm -rf dirname
```

Looking at other answsers, `git reset --hard HEAD`, `git checkout -f` and `git reflog` did not work, apparently because there is no HEAD to go back to, nor a commit to get the files back from.

Is there a way to get the files back?

Comment: Please update the accepted answer to the one actually allowing to get the files back.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way.

Usually, `git rm` checks the files have already been committed before deleting them, so you don't lose any of your work. However, using `-f` overrides this check.

In short:

- Don't use `-f`.
- Don't touch anything you haven't committed.

Comment: Just like unix - `-f` means you better be sure of what you are doing.

Comment: Considering I just did get my data back this is simply not true and shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

**Warning**: Running `git prune` without the `-n` option (1) **will erase** your unreachable data.

There may be a way, using [`git prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-prune) and [`git cat-file`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file).

Running `git prune -n` will list which objects would be removed by pruning:

```
$ git prune -n
9cc84ea9b4d95453215d0c26489d6a78694e0bc6 blob
c315143703752ef4d11ca7d93f2c324872b2ebff blob
```

Each line corresponds to a deleted file.

Now, using `git cat-file`, we are able to restore the contents of the removed file to a new file:

```
git cat-file -p 9cc84ea9b4d95453215d0c26489d6a78694e0bc6 > restored-filename
```

---

(1) From the `git prune` docs:

> NAME
>
>  git-prune - Prune all unreachable objects from the object database
>
>  OPTIONS
>
> -n
>
> --dry-run
>
> Do not remove anything; just report what it would remove.

Comment: This is the only answer that really helped! Thank you!

Comment: You are a LIFESAVER!  After working on a project for 12 hours and attempting an initial commit, I accidentally ran `git rm -rf .` to backout a change. I honestly thought all my work was lost forever. 

Note to future self - ALWAYS start with an empty repo then add files as you go along!

Answer (score 3):

if you haven't yet committed, you can recover the directory by doing:

```
git stash
git stash pop
git co dirname
```

Comment: This is clearly the best answer that solves the problem presented. It should come with the warnings provided in the accepted answer to be the perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

Nope, as far as I know. I believe that git unlinks the files, just like doing `rm -rf` does. It doesn't matter to it whether it knows about the files or not, it will gladly nuke the directory. Really, your only recourse is to try to use a file recovery tool as if you *had* done `rm -rf`

Answer (score 2):

If git is not tracking the `dirname` directory, it will not allow you to delete the directory with `git rm -rf` as it does not know about it. You will ( would have) get an error like

```
fatal: pathspec 'dirname' did not match any files
```

Only way you could have deleted is if you had done a `git add .` or `git add dirname` after the `git init`. If that is the case, your files are gone and you cannot get them back as it was never committed and git doesn't track it. It is as good as doing a `rm -rf` on a normal folder ( and can't recover unless you have backups)

Comment: Does it, though? I didn't test it, but I thought the -f flag will suppress that error.

Comment: Unless you use `-f`? That will "Override the up-to-date check.", whatever that means.

Comment: @Matt - No it does not suppress that. `-f` in `git rm` is only to override up-to-date check.

Comment: I just tested it on Git 1.7.5.4. `git rm -rf` would not touch an unstaged directory, but it will happily purge a staged but not committed one.

Answer (score 1):

`git reset --hard` helped while deletion was not commited yet and, generally speaking, deletion was interrupted by `Ctrl+Z`

Answer (score 0):

**git stash** is the command which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

first type "git stash"

then "git stash pop"

after you will see a list of deleted files. copy file names one by one and use

"git restore filename..." to discard changes in the working directory