# How to undo pull deleted local files which have never been committed?

Tags: git, github

I have worked on my project for 3 days.
When I finished the first function, I wanted to put files into a git repo. So, I used `git init.` and set up a remote repo. But I had to pull a readme file first. When the process is finished, everything in my local repo is gone. :(

My github repository has only a README file.

The command that I used are following:

1. `git init` to my work repo
2. `git add *`
3. `git remote add origin https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git`
4. `git pull origin master`

After that,  I got the README file and all my local files are gone! Are there ways to get them back?

Comment: Did you commit the files before pulling the readme file? (in git you can always commit without pulling, you only can't push without it)

Comment: A git pull does not delete local files in the way you describe. Are you absolutely certain they are not still there in another directory, perhaps up a level?

Comment: I didn't commit anything. I just init my local repo. Then, I pull the readme file. I forgot it would merge my local repo and delete all my local files.

Comment: @JanHudec you actually ***can push*** in Git without having committed work in progress, however, you'd probably get errors if you had no commits to push at all (i.e empty repo with no commits).

Comment: @FrenchBulldog we're going to need way more information about ***what were the exact commands you used*** before we can reasonably help you.

Comment: @FrenchBulldog: Git never ever deletes files that were not added to it. Git also never merges when there are modifications of files that are known to it or when anything has been added and not committed. Can you write down the sequence, in specific commands, as closely as you remember it? (The shell history file might be of help)

Comment: See also [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771679/how-to-undo-a-git-rm-r-f#comment25923331_17773646) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17771679/how-to-undo-a-git-rm-r-f/17773646#17773646), which may be applicable.

Comment: @Cupcake, Jan Hudec I have specified my question.

Comment: @FrenchBulldog I replicated the steps you have above, and I didn't get the same result. `git pull origin master` did not overwrite any of the untracked files I had in the folder after doing `git init`. Did you actually run `git add` after you ran `git init`?

Comment: @Cupcake I am sorry. I over one step. I ran command `git add *` after the `git init` command. I did that because the first time I want to commit and push everything into github but I realized that I did not pull yet. So, I used command `git pull` after `git add *`